# Tab bar in storyboard with reused ViewControllers IOS5

Tags: ios5, tabs, storyboard

My program consists of Tab bar with 5 tabs. User interface of tabs 1, 2 and 3 is the same, the only difference is in the logic of representation of content e.g. new, top ... I have a chain of ViewControllers in storyboard, my question is how can I reuse my ViewControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to re-use your view controller code files .m and .h or are you looking to reuse your storyboard object that has the UI?

Reusing your code is easily accomplished.  Each storyboard object can be associated with a custom class.  Its on the object inspector on the right under identity.  You can assign the same view controller class to one or more storyboard objects - allowing you to re-use your code.

If you want to reuse your the view layout you created in the storyboard and reuse the same storyboard but with different view controller classes - to manage the different functionality - that is not currently possible.

A potential work around is to define a custom UIView by adding a xib file and putting your user interface in that.  Then create a custom UIView subclass and assign it.  Then in your storyboards, you can initialize the custom view and add it as a subview.  You would reference the custom class to manage the UI.

Unless your UI is very complicated, it is usually easier to simply re-create the UI on separate storyboards and assign an appropriate view controller to them.  You can duplicate a storyboard using cmd-d, or simply copy and paste.   You should do this before you connect the UI objects to any code because sometimes the copy and paste will carry over the old reference.

So, setup your tabbar controller, connect a separate navigation controller to each tab and then connect a view controller (view or tableview or pageController, etc) as the root view to each navigation controller.  Then setup your UI, then assign your custom subclass, then connect the UI to properties in your subclass.  Remember, you can re-use your subclasses across multiple view controllers in your storyboard because each storyboard will create a new instance of that subclass.  You may just need some additional logic to manage things correctly on each tabs function.

well no code, just my .02
happy new year.

Comment: Thank you very much, Happy New Year! I have done mostly as you described - as the UI is similar in several tabs I have just copy pasted View controllers and connected to tab navigation controllers (all was performed in storyboard).

Comment: The problem is that I have singleton class to keep global vars, so I suppose I'll need to have several singleton classes for each tab, and the second problem is that I don't know how determine which tab navigation controller has called view controller in order to perform specific sorting of data, please kindly give an advise... 1.Is it correct to have several singletons?, 2.How determine which navigation controller is managing my view controller?

Comment: Hi @David - you'll find much debate about using singletons.  Personally I have no issues with their use, but my best practice advice would be this: If you need to store one or two properties, use the app delegate, it is in effect a handy singleton.  If you have a number of properties along with methods, then isolate to one small purpose and limit your singleton for just that purpose.  Avoid the temptation to fill up your singleton with disparate functionality as it tends to lead to spaghetti code. If you need to share a model across your tabbar view controllers, a singleton is an ok approach.

Comment: Thank you CocoaEv, for the second part of my question. the answer is: NSUInteger index = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:self.navigationController];

Comment: @David - thanks for that little snippet I wasn't aware of that approach but I just tried it and it works great. good job!  I was also going to mention to you to investigate if making your view controllers a delegate to tabBar using UITabBarControllerDelegate or UITabBarDelegate would improve your design.  There is one handy method that informs you when a view controller is selected.

Comment: Another workaround to make it possible to reuse a storyboard-instantiated view controller is to make the code of that view controller driven by a delegate. When you instantiate the view controller from the storyboard you can decide what delegate class should be passed to it, modifying its behavior accordingly. Your storyboard-instantiated view controller just needs to be set up to ask its delegate for whatever the custom behavior is.